# Extending javascript literal object

Tags: javascript

Why JohnDoe.whoAreYou() does return undefined ?:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var JohnDoe = {
        //public property
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",

        //public method
        whoAreYou: function() {
          alert( "I am literal object and my name is " + this.toString());
        },
        whatIsYourAge: function() {
          alert("My age is " + this.Age);
        }               
    };    
  </script>

  <script>
    JohnDoe.Age = 10;
    JohnDoe.toString = function() {this.firstName + " " + this.lastName};
    JohnDoe.whoAreYou();    
    JohnDoe.whatIsYourAge();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for starters, you want this: JohnDoe.toString = function() { return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you aren't returning anything from this function. Try like this:

```
JohnDoe.toString = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};
```

Comment: Thanks I'm too used to rebol that doesn't need return.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to creating objects is very limiting.

You should rather create a new instance from a constructor and pass in the values to that function.

```
function User(firstName, lastName, age) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   this.age = age;
   // set name etc here
}

User.prototype.toString = function() {
    // Note the "return" so this function actual returns something
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; 
}
User.prototype.whoAreYou = function() {
    alert( "I am literal object and my name is " + this.toString());
}

var JohnDoe = new User("John", "Doe", 10); 
JohnDoe.whoAreYou();


var someoneElse = new User("Someone", "Else", 15); 
someoneElse.whoAreYou();
```

Comment: uhh ... if he puts a "return" keyword in his "toString" function it'll all work just fine ... when he calls the functions as property references off his "JohnDoe" object, then `this` will indeed refer to that object

Comment: @Pointy yeah, guess I misread the question, guess I'm to tired :/ Reworked it to give some advice on object creation.

Comment: Thanks Ivo, I'm not considering prototype yet but I will then I'll look at your sample :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you forgot to `return` the value from the "toString" function you defined.